# Character movement in Unity

Tags: unity

For an endless runner game such as Subway Surfer, in order to move your character so smoothly in both z-axis and x-axis, which component of the followings is better:

`CharacterController` or `RigidBody`?

Can we use both of them together; if so, will it have any effect on the performance of our game?

Comment: The CharacterController already has a built-in RigidBody, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Both options may be overkill for your needs. All of the gameplay of a lane-based runner could be handled with an integer representing which "lane" the player is in, and some scalars for their progress along the track/obstacles' progress toward them, and maybe an elevation value if you need multi-tiered play. You might not need interactions with physics forces here. Try breaking down "what problem do I want this component to solve?" versus "what problems does each alternative solve?"

Comment: https://github.com/dgkanatsios/InfiniteRunner3D hopefully what u r looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can only use one. Use the `Character Controller`, it will give you fine tune control with fixed speeds. Using a `Rigidbody` for player control is only useful in special cases.